# Returning stored procedure output through ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, stored-procedures, pdo

I currently have a working process where an ajax call is made in my blade which makes a call through the controller and that function hits a stored procedure call using PDO. This call is successful and my stored procedure executes/inserts properly and is set to return back my output. My only question now is:

How can I take the output from the stored procedure and pass it back into my blade for a hidden input? There is no page refresh, so when the AJAX call is successful then I want to put my output from the service file into a hidden input in the blade. How can I properly do this?

BLADE:

```
$.ajax({

   type:'POST',
   url:'campaigns/createCampaign',
   data:{campaignName:campaignName, attribute:attribute},
    _token: '{{ csrf_token() }}',
   success:function(data){
        intro_modal.hide();
   }
});
```

CONTROLLER:

```
public function createCampaign(Request $request)
{
    $campaignName = $request->campaignName;
    $attribute = $request->attribute;

    $campaignService = new CampaignService();
    $createCampaign = $campaignService->createCampaign($campaignName, (int) $attribute);

    //return response()->$campaignService;
}
```

SERVICE:

```
function createCampaign($campaignName, $attribute){

    $stmt = \DB::connection('odbc')->getPdo()->prepare('CALL PROCEDURES.INSERT_CAMPAIGN(?,?,?)');

    $stmt->bindValue(1,$campaignName, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindValue(2,$attribute, $attribute==0 ? PDO::PARAM_NULL : PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(3,$out2, PDO::PARAM_INT);

    $stmt->execute();

}
```

Comment: I understand well you want to have the latest `Campaign` in a hidden input?

Comment: Yes. In the service, ```$out2``` is my latest campaign ID. I just want to have it as a hidden input once the ajax call is successful, so I need to return $out2 back after that

Comment: I will propose you my solution in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your **createCampaign**

```php
function createCampaign($campaignName, $attribute){

    $stmt = \DB::connection('odbc')->getPdo()->prepare('CALL PROCEDURES.INSERT_CAMPAIGN(?,?,?)');

    $stmt->bindValue(1,$campaignName, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindValue(2,$attribute, $attribute==0 ? PDO::PARAM_NULL : PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(3,$out2, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();

    return $out2;
}
```

In your **Controller**

Use these class:

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response;
use Illuminate\Http\Response as HttpResponse;
```

**Return a JSON response:**

```php
public function createCampaign(Request $request)
{
    $campaignName = $request->campaignName;
    $attribute = $request->attribute;

    $campaignService = new CampaignService();
    $createdCampaignId = $campaignService->createCampaign($campaignName, (int) $attribute);

    return Response::json(["campaign_id" => $createdCampaignId)
            ->setStatusCode(HttpResponse::HTTP_OK);
}
```

In your **Blade template**

```
$.ajax({

   type:'POST',
   url:'campaigns/createCampaign',
   data:{campaignName:campaignName, attribute:attribute},
    _token: '{{ csrf_token() }}',
   success:function(data){
        intro_modal.hide();
       // data.campaign_id will contains the new campain id
   }
});
```

After you will just need to insert the value of the `data.campaign_id` with `jQuery` for example.

Comment: Thank you! I do think there's a syntax error here though ```return Response::json(["campaign_id" => $createdCampaignId)```

Comment: I fixed that though, but now ```console.log(data.campaign_id)``` is null so I'm trying to see why

Comment: can you do `console.log(data)`

Comment: Yes it shows the object ```OUT_CAMPAIGN_ID: null```

Comment: the OUT_CAMPAIGN_ID that's returned is an integer if that makes a difference

Comment: the JSON format handle correctly both integer and float numbers